# Create dynamic function based on global constant in php

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make some helpers function in **Laravel** but this question is fully related to PHP. I am asking this question for my personal curiosity. If this question sounds silly then ignore it, otherwise let me known your solution.

**Helpers.php**

```
<?php

! defined('FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY') && define('FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY', 'feedback'); // alert, flash or feedback

if (!function_exists(FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY)) {
    // Create function dynamically based on FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY constant
}
```

Comment: Before you could use `create_function` but now it is removed from php

Comment: Explain more what it is you’re trying to do, and most of all *why*.

Comment: `create_function` became obsolete after closures were introduced. `$func = function() { /* your code */ };` to create anonymous functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be possible to define function with dynamic name as [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function) has been deprecated since PHP 7.2 and removed in PHP 8.

If there are only 2 or 3 values for global constant **FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY**, then you can create definitions for all 2 or 3 possible named functions conditionally.

This approach may not be useful if the possible values for global constant **FLLASH_MESSAGE_KEY** are many in number or not known

```php
//helpers.php
<?php

if (defined('FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY')) {
    if (!function_exists('alert') && FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY === 'alert') {
        function alert($message, $type = 'alert')
        {
            $message = '<div class="'.$type.'">'.$message.'</div>';
            return $message;
        }
    }

    if (!function_exists('feedback') && FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY === 'feedback') {
        function feedback($message, $type = 'feedback')
        {
            $message = '<div class="'.$type.'">'.$message.'</div>';
            return $message;
        }
    }
}
```

And specific to Laravel, you can then define global constant in `public/index.php` like

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
define('FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY', 'alert');


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists($maintenance = __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require $maintenance;
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
)->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```